# Mocha and web3.js without await

Tags: web3js, javascript, mocha

Awaiting the resolution of calls to a node works for me, like this example:

```
describe('some contract', async function () {

    ...

    it('data should be written correctly', async function () {
        let expectedResult = 1;
        let actualResult = await instance.getSomeData(param1);
        assert(actualResult == expectedResult); 
    })
```

What gives me weird behaviour - a timeout to be specific, is when I try to assert inside the callback of a promise like this:

```
describe('some contract', async function () {

    ...

    it('data should be written correctly', async function () {
        let expectedResult = 1;
        instance.getSomeData(param1).then(result => {
            assert(result == expectedResult); 
        })
    })
```

Is there any way to do this, or is the only way to await the result and then assert?

Comment: What is `actualResult` in the second piece of code???

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971167/how-to-increase-timeout-for-a-single-test-case-in-mocha

Comment: @goodvibration edited for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather a JS question, but anyway, here the answer, since it's useful to know when writing Ethereum tests in JS:

The problem with your second code fragment is that your test case is considered as done before your "then"-part is executed. I would recommend to try not to mix `async/await` and `then` as far as possible.

Variant 1 (no async function, return the promise):

```
it('data should be written correctly', function () {
    let expectedResult = 1;

    return instance.getSomeData(param1).then(result => {
        assert(result == expectedResult);
    })
})
```

Variant 2 (async function with await):

```
it('data should be written correctly', async function () {
    let expectedResult = 1;

    var result = await instance.getSomeData(param1);
    assert(result == expectedResult);
})
```

Moreover, I am not quite sure if this is a good idea:

```
describe('some contract', async function () {...})
```

There is no reason to have an async function here when you only have `it`-calls inside?

Comment: You're right that adding the async to a describe call is definitely a bad idea. It can cause tests to fail in a seemingly "random" way. It should definitely just be `describe('some contract', function () {...})`.

Comment: That helped (also your note about the extra async in describe) - only thing missing is that mocha seems not to exit on itself, only solution is to call `mocha --exit`